# open a non-standard compression .tar.lzma file extracted from firmware download

Tags: linux, tools, decompress

We are trying to examine a firmware download for a product we have running on our local network.  Using the command

```
binwalk -Me filename
```

we generated a folder that contains the following content:

```
184A46C.cramfs
276466C.cramfs
6C.cramfs
C2426C.cramfs
cramfs-root/
cramfs-root-0/
cramfs-root-1/
cramfs-root-2/
```

Binwalk appears to have opened the CramFS just fine.  So navigating into cramfs-root and running the file command, we see the following:

```
app.tar.lzma:    data
copy_logo:       data
cramfs.img:      empty
dvrCmd.tar.gz:   data
hicore.tar.lzma: data
hisi.tar.lzma:   data
logo.tar.lzma:   data
misc.tar.lzma:   data
new_10.bin:      data
player.bin:      PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, UPX compressed
start.sh:        data
uImage:          u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-3.0.8, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel     Image (Not compressed), 2854980 bytes, Tue Apr 14 10:16:02 2015, Load Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, Header CRC: 0x6C502F38, Data     CRC: 0xE9307D6E
version:         ASCII text
webs.tar.lzma:   data
```

Other than the uImage file, which apparently contains a linux kernel, most of the files here are apparently .tar.lzma files.  Attempting to open one of them as a normal .tar.lzma is not working for us.

```
tar --lzma -xvf logo.tar.lzma
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Trying something else:

```
unlzma logo.tar.lzma
unlzma: Decoder error
```

lzmainfo seems to think it is valid, however, but it is calculating it as a laughably large, multi-petabyte file.  I am quite sure it is not.

```
lzmainfo logo.tar.lzma

logo.tar.lzma
Uncompressed size:             8351652399384 MB (8757342266336797407 bytes)
Dictionary size:               525 MB (2^29 bytes)
Literal context bits (lc):     0
Literal pos bits (lp):         2
Number of pos bits (pb):       4
```

I've uploaded the file [here](http://ge.tt/18asCBf2) if you care to look at it.

Comment: We can infer that, ultimately, there is an image file somewhere in there.  So is there a known-plaintext technique that can be used to break the "encryption" (non-standard compression)?  Thanks.

Comment: I saw similar files in Hikvision firmware, where the tar.lzma files were encrypted.

Comment: @ebux How do you know that the files were actually encrypted, rather than merely compressed in a non-standard way?  Is there a tool you can use to detect encryption, determine the cypher used, etc.?

Comment: @ebux Also: although the .tar.lzma files are un-openable, the linux kernel is clearly visible in plain text.  Wouldn't it be possible to run the linux kernel in an emulator, and use the emulator to read the file system?  I opened the chassis, looked at the board, and googled the part numbers for chips I saw.  I didn't see any crypto devices on the board, so I'm going to assume that the decryption is implemented in the firmware image itself, in the plaintext portion.

Comment: In my case, the kernel contained an initramfs, which performed the decryption using a kernel device.

Comment: @ebux What is a "kernel device" in this context?  Is it hardware or software?  And what eventually happened with your project?  Were you able to view/modify your firmware or not?

Comment: It is a software device implemented in the kernel. I just started to see this firmware now, so I don't have too much progress.