# Using QEMU to boot arm uImage kernel

Tags: qemu, kernel

I'm currently trying to reverse engineer the firmware for the Swann DVR16-4500 security camera system. I successfully extracted the cramfs filesystem and now I have the following files inside the cramfs-root directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2289232 Dec 31  1969 gui_res.tar.lzma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     744 Dec 31  1969 new_10.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Dec 15  2015 Player_ml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  824944 Dec 31  1969 player.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    2936 Dec 31  1969 start.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6213824 Dec 31  1969 sys_app.tar.lzma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3585544 Dec 31  1969 uImage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1881320 Dec 31  1969 WebComponents.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  689296 Dec 31  1969 webs.tar.lzma
```

I tried using unlzma and tar --lzma -xvf to extract the *.tar.lzma files, but I had no luck. I came across [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/open-a-non-standard-compression-tar-lzma-file-extracted-from-firmware-download) which suggested running the kernel in an emulator in the hopes of finding the necessary extraction tools there. I've been tearing through QEMU documentation and online videos but I can't figure out exactly what I need to do to get QEMU to run the uImage kernel using qemu-system-arm. What do I need to do in order to get the kernel to run?

Comment: what happened when you ran `tar --lzma xvf <file>`? Were there error messages? What was the output? Did you run the `file` command against the `*.tar.lzma` files? If so, what were the results, and were the results [manually verified](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15088/lzma-file-format-not-recognized-details-enclosed)?  Did you inspect a hex dump of any of the `*.tar.lzma` files? If so what were the results?

Comment: what does `file` say  on `uImage`?

Comment: When I run `tar --lzma xvf ` I get the following response: `xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now` the file command just says all of the files are "data". When I run lzmainfo the command is satisfied that it is an lzma file, but it says that the file will be over a petabyte when it's uncompressed, similar to the post I referenced above. 
`

Comment: When I run file on the uImage file I get the following response:  `uImage: u-boot legacy uImage, Linux-3.10.0, Linux/ARM, OS Kernel Image (Not compressed), 3585480 bytes, Thu Mar 10 11:17:03 2016, Load Address: 0x40008000, Entry Point: 0x40008000, Header CRC: 0x253B9638, Data CRC: 0x5C656DD5

Comment: Sorry, just speculating here. But IIRC there's a difference between `.tar.xz` and `.tar.lzma` ... and in fact the man page strongly suggests that the resulting archive is filtered through `xz` or `lzma` respectively, although both use LZMA as the compression algorithm. Also, do you have `xz` installed? `xzdec` or `xz-utils` on Debian/Ubuntu.